# Could not find a part of the path. 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Decks'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path, directory

I am newbie in WPF and C#. I am trying to use static resources to declare objects in XAML. But I got issues:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Decks'
>   XAML:

This is my code so far:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Session x:Key="session"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="15" x:Name="pageLayoutStackPanel" 
            DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=session}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Your Decks:" FontSize="18"/>
        <ListView Height="320" ItemsSource="{Binding decks}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Create new deck " FontSize="18" Margin="0,8,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

</StackPanel>
```

This is my `Session` class:

```
class Session
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> decks 
    { 
      get; private set; 
    }    

    public Session()
    {
        decks = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        string defaultFolder = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string navigateToFolder = "Decks";
        string sourceDir = Path.Combine(defaultFolder, navigateToFolder);
        Console.WriteLine(sourceDir);
        string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt")
           .Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();

        foreach(var txtfile in txtFiles)
        {
            decks.Add(txtfile);
            Console.WriteLine(txtfile);
        }
    }
}
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KJb5.jpg)

How to fix it? And what is going on?

Comment: Could you please search for "Decks.XAML" and update here?

Comment: @Sham there is no Decks.XAML. Decks is just a folder in which i wanted to save my files.  Decks located in Debug folder. "..\..\Debug\Decks".